# Not all extensions appear in Add New list

Tags: joomla, extension

I want to install an extension in Joomla 3.5.1 (CiviCRM 4.6.15, Php 5.6.19, Linux, been using CiviCRM for several years, continuous upgrading).

But, the extension isn't appearing for me ("SPARKPOST / CIVICRM INTEGRATION 1.3.1"). I've refreshed, waited a day and refreshed again, but it doesn't appear. It's been released for more than two months, although the most recent version is from beginning of April.

I don't know what else to try. I would like to avoid manually downloading and installing the extension, because I'm concerned that it wouldn't show future updates if it's not showing the actual released version.

Many extensions are listed under the Add New list of extensions, but ***some newer ones*** (as far as I can tell) are not, although they're listed as available on CiviCRM.(https://civicrm.org/extension-civicrm-compatibility/civicrm-46)

Two of the missing items, for example: "SPARKPOST EMAIL EXTENSION FOR CIVICRM 1.0" and "SPARKPOST / CIVICRM INTEGRATION 1.3.1".

Another one (with a more recent release date than the two above "OUTBOUND DOMAIN ENFORCEMENT VERSION 1.4" **IS** listed on my "New Extensions" tab, so it's not just a date thing.

Comment: We're looking into what we need to do to get listed within civicrm. I will respond here when we get more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extensions don't get added to the "Add New" tab just because they are on the https://civicrm.org/extensions. They must be approved by the CiviCRM team first. We are working to get our extension published into that list to make it easier for users to install.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications. Since the CivCRM extensions page lists this one (and others) as "CMS Independent, I assumed it had actually been reviewed/tested on all platforms. That seems a small oversight in the release process. I can see how the developer would list it that way, but an additional "status" value on the extensions detail page to show what had been reviewed or not would have saved some bother. Also, it might be a way of gathering opinion, by added a voting button to show if there was interest in getting it reviewed/available.